# Cannot rotate to both portrait orientations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, screen-rotation

i have added both the portrait orientations to the .plist for iPad and normal, how ever it is still not roating round to button on top portrait :S here is my code in the firstviewcontroller.m

```
    // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in all your view controllers, possible you have a base one and an overriden one for each of iPhone/iPad. Each of them must return YES (or YES/NO depending on the orientation you want to support).